# Close file for reading before start writing

Tags: java, file, file-writing, try-with-resources

I wrote a method which replace some lines in a file (it's not the purpose of this question). Everything works fine, but I'm wondering if file is closed for reading when I start writing. I'd like to ensure that my solution is safe. That's what I've done:

```
private void replaceCodeInTranslationFile(File file, String code) {
  if (file.exists()) {
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()), Charset.defaultCharset())) {
        String output = this.getLinesWithUpdatedCode(lines, code);
        this.replaceFileWithContent(file, output); // is it safe?
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Method `replaceFileWithContent()` looks like this:

```
private void replaceFileWithContent(File file, String content) throws IOException {
  try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath())) {
    fileOut.write(content.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()));
  }
}
```

I think that `try-with-resources` closes resource at the end of a statement, so this code can be potentially the source of problems. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, it does. That's the *only* thing it does. Strange question.

Answer (score 0):

Read / Write lock implementations may be helpful for this kind of scenario to ensure thread safe operations.
Refer this http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/read-write-locks.html for more..